# How to groupby external time series data together

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate, grouping

I have been trying to groupby some state data together. This is how my data looks like for example, with Date as the index and the rest is features:

| Date | Population | Num_Men | Num_Women | State | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 500 | 300 | 200 | NY | North |
| 2020-02-01 | 800 | 500 | 300 | GL | Middle |
| 2020-02-01 | 1000 | 400 | 600 | "" | Middle |
| 2020-02-01 | 200 | 50 | 150 | nan | Middle |
| 2020-02-01 | 600 | 400 | 200 | NY | North |

I know how to group the NY states ones, but if I want to group the ones with state values: GL, "", and nan together. I'm not sure how to do that.

I was looking for the final result to look like:

| Date | Population | Num_Men | Num_Women | State | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 500 | 300 | 200 | NY | North |
| 2020-02-01 | 2000 | 950 | 1050 | GL | Middle |
| 2020-02-01 | 600 | 400 | 200 | NY | North |

I did something like this: df.groupby(df.index, {'State': ["GL", "", np.nan]}, but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `df['State'] = df['State'].replace("", 'GL').fillna('GL')` Then you can groupby `State`.

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `replace` then `groupby` with `sum` and `first`

```
df.State = df.State.replace({"''":np.nan,'nan':np.nan})
out = df.groupby(['Region','Date'],as_index=False).\      
          agg({'Population':'sum',
               'Num_Men':'sum',
               'Num_Women':'sum',
               'State':'first'})
Out[99]: 
   Region        Date  Population  Num_Men  Num_Women State
0  Middle  2020-02-01        2000      950       1050    GL
1   North  2020-01-01         500      300        200    NY
2   North  2020-02-01         600      400        200    NY
```

Comment: I see. But what if I have a lot of these "weird" state values? I feel like I can use apply?

Comment: @user3002936 find them all , mask them to Nan